# How to use multiple independent images as a base in a multi-stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building a dev environment that installs many SDKs and tools. They can be standalone or depend on others. For readability purposes and to make it cache-friendly I want to separate each "component" in its own stage.

So, for example, if I wanted to install different python libraries in separate stages, I would do something like this:

```
FROM alpine as with_python
RUN apt install -y python3 python3-pip

FROM with_python as with_pytest
RUN pip3 install pytest

FROM with_pytest as with_yaml
RUN pip3 install PyYAML

FROM with_yaml as final_image
```

But this makes `with_yaml` depend on `with_pytest`, which shouldn't be the case. I want to do something like this:

```
FROM alpine as with_python
RUN apt install -y python3 python3-pip

FROM with_python as with_pytest
RUN pip3 install pytest

FROM with_python as with_yaml
RUN pip3 install PyYAML

FROM with_pytest, with_yaml as final_image
```

This way I can modify either stage without affecting the other - only the dependent stages would get rebuilt, which is the `final_image` in this case.
Is there a way to achieve this? Or do I want the wrong thing, and there's a better approach?

I know I can `COPY --from` each "artifact", but with the amount of packages and the fact that some of them modify the environment, it isn't feasible.

Answer (score -1):

As a general approach, I wouldn't be using alpine based image for python applications,

**Standard PyPI wheels don’t work on Alpine**

Most Python packages these days include binary wheels on PyPI, significantly speeding install time. But if you’re using Alpine Linux you need to compile all the C code in every Python package that you use.

See here eventual issues you can have https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

You can end up resolving this, then another one will show up and so on and on...

Comment: Python packages are just an example to illustrate the point